# How to set a cron job on Skygear to run every 12 hours?

Tags: python, cron, parse-cloud-code, skygear

Trying to set a cron job on my Skygear python cloud code, but not sure what I should enter in the decorator. I only know that it will work for units in second, but how to schedule a job to run every 12 hours? It is hard to calculate the seconds every time.

My code is like this, the function is to call a POST request:

```
@skygear.every('@every 43200s')
def post_req():
    print ('scheduled to run every 12 hours')
    url = myurl
    ref = something
    r = requests.post(myurl, data = {'token':some_token, 'ref':something})
```

It actually works but is there some ways to write in a better format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `skygear.every` also [accepts crontab notation](https://docs.skygear.io/cloud-code/guide/scheduled)… so [`0 */12 * * *`](http://crontab.guru/#0_*/12_*_*_*) could also do the trick.

Edit: Reading the [robfig/cron](https://github.com/robfig/cron/blob/master/doc.go) docs, the best solution would actually be just `@every 12h`

Comment: Under the hook, skygear is using https://github.com/robfig/cron to parse the crontab notation.